# Copyinf files with spaces in the file name using scp

Tags: shell, unix, scp

I'm trying to copy files using `scp` through a shell script. My piece of code is:

```
for file in $result;
do
scp username@hostname:"$feed" destination
done
```

Where the result has the list of files to be copied. But it is not copying the files which have spaces in their names e.g.:

```
new assignment.xls
```

Kindly provide a suggestion.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "$file"?

Comment: why the `;` at the end of first line (after `$result`) ?

Comment: yes sorry a typo..that should be $file

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in $result;
do
name=`echo $file | sed 's/ /\\ //'`
scp username@hostname:"$name" destination
done
```

Comment: scp username@hostname:"/$feed" destination....is this how should be given in the script

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${result}" | while read FileName
 do
   scp "user@hostname:${FileName}" destination
 done
```

(adapted for `while read` instead of `for in`}

encapsulate the whole source, not just the file/path. `destionation` may also need a quote is space or other meta char is inside

Comment: this gives me a message that argument list is too long..My requirement is to copy one file at a time to local machine via scp and then from local to hdfs location.As i have space constrataint in the local

Comment: modified for using while read to ensure 1 file per iteration (and thus 1 file per line in result)